# Value of type System.Drawing.Image cannot be converted to 1-dimensional array of System.Drawing.Image

Tags: vb.net, image, tabcontrol

That's my code:

```
Dim mimage = Image.FromStream(stream)
Me.TabControl2.ImageList.Images.AddRange(mimage) -> Here
Me.TabControl2.SelectedTab.ImageIndex = 0
Me.TabControl2.ImageList.Images.RemoveAt(0)
```

And it gives me that error (title). What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AddRange Requires an Array

```
Me.TabControl2.ImageList.Images.Add(mimage)
Me.TabControl2.ImageList.Images.AddRange({mimage})
```